# Register User form MySQL Syntax Error

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

When I submit the form to register a new user on my website, it submits, however it does not submit to the database and i'm getting an error saying this:

> Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near '####, 800800800)' at line 2 Whole query: mysql_query

Here is my MySQL Query:

```
    $fname    =   $_POST['fnamein'];
    $lname    =   $_POST['lnamein'];
    $email    =   $_POST['emailin'];
    $phone    =   $_POST['phonein'];
    $password =   sha1($_POST['passwordin']);

    $query='INSERT INTO directoryi (Fname, Lname, password, email, phone) 
    VALUES ('.$fname.', '.$lname.', '.$password.', '.$email.', '.$phone.')';
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if (!$result) {
        $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
        $message .= 'Whole query: ' . mysql_query;
        die($message);
    }

    echo '<h2>Thank you for registering!</h2>';

    mysql_free_result($result);
    mysql_close($dbconnect);
    ?>
```

And my HTML Form:

```
        <form action="register.php" method='post'>
            <input type="text" class="input-small" style="width: 46%;" name="fnamein" placeholder="First Name">
            <input type="text" class="input-small" style="width: 46%;" name="lnamein" placeholder="Last Name">
            <input type="text" class="input" style="width: 46%;" name="emailin" placeholder="Email">
            <input type="text" class="input" style="width: 46%;" name="phonein" placeholder="ex. 7171234567">
            <input type="password" class="input" style="width: 96%;" name="passwordin" placeholder="Password">
            <button type="submit" class="btn">Register</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: Please _don't_ build a query using string concatenation - this is one of the most common security flaws. Read up on SQL Injection

Answer (score 5):

To answer your question directly, string literals must be wrap with single quotes,

```
$query="INSERT INTO directoryi (Fname, Lname, password, email, phone) 
        VALUES ('" .$fname. "', '" .$lname. "', '".$password."', '".$email."', '".$phone."')";
```

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the data types of your fields, my guess is that you aren't properly providing single-quotes around the insert values.  Try this:

```
$query="INSERT INTO directoryi (Fname, Lname, password, email, phone) 
VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', '$password', '$email', '$phone')";
```

Note that this assumes all fields are string type fields (like varchar).

You also have significant SQL injection vulnerability, and are using `mysql_*` functions which are deprecated.  I would strongly suggest you learn how to use mysqli or PDO with prepared statements.